# Integrating External API (Moltin) with Meteor

Tags: api, meteor, moltin

I am trying to integrate [Moltin](https://www.moltin.com/) with Meteor and can't figure out how to authenticate it. I installed it with `meteor npm install moltin`.

Here is the guide for using [Moltin with Node](https://www.moltin.com/quick-start/node/) and I followed the Meteor format to be used `import Moltin from 'moltin';` instead of the usual Node `require` as the [Meteor npm guide](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html) states.

I guess the main problem is figuring out what to put what where and how to format it.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Your question is too vague, do you have any specific errors you can share with us?

Comment: Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Y9XSifyc)

Comment: @Sean Here is the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Y9XSifyc)